# Which component types does the salesforce.com Metadata API *not* support?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I'm looking for a list of component types that the salesforce.com Metadata API does not support. As an example, I don't believe it supports assignment rules.

Someone at salesforce published a list a while back, but I can't find it and don't know if it is updated.

Comment: I've never seen a published list, assignment rules is the only one that I've come across but most of our deployments just involve code, pages, layouts and objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Metadata API documentation here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm?SearchType=Stem